# Flash WebSocket class/library

Tags: flash, websocket

Where can I find Flash WebSocket class/library for Flash (not Flash builder, no mx classes)? Please provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[websocket-as](https://github.com/y8/websocket-as) is probably the closest you'll find. However, it implements an older version of the WebSockets protocol, Hixei-75. Most browsers that have WebSockets (either on by default such as Chrome, or off by default like Firefox 4 and Opera 11) implement Hixie-76. The HyBi version of the protocol are coming soon.

You might be able to adapt websocket-as to support the new protocol by looking at the implementation in [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) which implements Hixie-76. web-socket-js is a shim/polyfill for WebSockets support in Javascript. web-socket-js uses mx.* classes however. There is a [development branch](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js/tree/hybi-07) of web-socket-js which implements HyBi-07.

**Update**:

Another project that tracks the current HyBi protocol pretty well is [AS3WebSocket](https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket). AS3WebSocket uses some mx.* classes however.